# Slides API - How to crop Images?

Tags: google-api, google-slides-api

I'm using Google slides API.
I need to take an image from a Presentation A that I want to copy-paste in a Presentation B.

I use the "presentations().get" method from Presentation A to obtain the image. Then, I use the "createImage" and "updateImageProperties" requests in the batchUpdate method to update Presentation B.

Unfortunately I cannot update cropProperties, transparency, brightness, contrast and recolor that are read-only properties.

So my image in Presentation B is not the same as the image get from Presentation A (any cropped image render terribly for instance).

Here is the part of my code in question.

```py
def insert_image(pageElement, page_id):
    image_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
    requests = []
    requests.append({'createImage': {'objectId': image_id, 'url': pageElement['image']['contentUrl'], 'elementProperties': {
        'pageObjectId': page_id, 'size': pageElement['size'], 'transform': pageElement['transform']}}})
    requests.append({'updateImageProperties': {'objectId': image_id,
                                               'imageProperties': pageElement['image']['imageProperties'], 'fields': "outline,shadow,link"}})
    return requests
```

Is there any workaround to apply the correct Properties to my image B ?

I am thinking about 2 ways : 
- using Google AppScript
- saving the image as the cropped image on a disk

Any help would be amazing on this subject :)

Comment: Can I ask you about the result of the 2 ways you did? By the way, your script in your question is python?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue a while back. It's a bummer that the crop properties are read-only. I found a not-so-ideal solution. It's not the fastest or the cleanest, but it gets the job done. Mine was done with Apps Script, but I believe it should be the same with batch requests.
Basically, the steps are:

1. Resize the image to whatever dimensions you want using setWidth()
   and setHeight().
   https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/image
   The image will probably get distorted based on your resize.

   2. Grab the image url from the shape.https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/image#getContentUrl()
      Replace the image in the shape with the same url and set the crop
      value to true. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/image#replace(String,Boolean) This should reset the image to the correct proportions, cropped in the resized frame.

Unfortunately, this is slow because it has to fetch every image again. Also, you can't control the exact cropping. It will be centered in the frame.

Hope this helps